# What are JavaScript source files as described in 'Google JavaScript Style Guide'

Tags: javascript

I am still a novice. I am reading the 'Google JS Styling Guide'. I wonder - what does [section 3 'Source File Structure'](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#source-file-structure) refer to? It begins:

> A source file consists of, in order:
>
> 1. License or copyright information, if present
> 2. @fileoverview JSDoc, if present
> 3. goog.module statement
> 4. goog.require statements
> 5. The file's implementation

Comment: If you read sections 3.1 - 3.5 it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * @fileoverview Description of file, its uses and information
     * about its dependencies.
     * @package
     */

    goog.module('my.test.helpers');
    goog.module.declareLegacyNamespace();
    goog.setTestOnly();

    const MyClass = goog.require('some.package.MyClass');
    const NsMyClass = goog.require('other.ns.MyClass');
```

it basically means the above format. i think this example uses the google closure library.

https://github.com/google/closure-library

Answer (score -1):

They are files, containing JavaScript source code.

i.e. Any `.js` file.